# Cell Editing in PrimeFaces get null

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem: when I'm trying to edit a cell i'm getting *null* in *oldValue* and *newValue*. Here is a code for XHTML:

```
<h:form id="tabela">  
     <p:contextMenu for="tabelaPrzypomnien" widgetVar="cMenu">     
        <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="PF('carsTable').showCellEditor();return false;"/>    
        <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('cMenu').hide()"/>    
    </p:contextMenu>
 <p:dataTable id="tabelaPrzypomnien" value="#{obslugaUzytkownikow.listaZadan}" var="zadania" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"  
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                 paginator="true" lazy="true" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable">   
<f:facet name="header">  
            In-Cell Editing  
        </f:facet>     

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{obslugaZadan.onCellEdit}"/>
        <p:column headerText="id grupy">  
            <h:outputText value="#{zadania.id_grupy}" />  
        </p:column>   

        <p:column headerText="Temat" sortBy="temat">  
               <p:cellEditor>  
                   <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{zadania.temat}" />
                   </f:facet>  
                   <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{zadania.temat}" style="width:96%" />
                   </f:facet>  
               </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Deadline" sortBy="deadline">  
            <h:outputText value="#{zadania.deadline}" />  
        </p:column> 

    </p:dataTable>
```

and ObslugaZadan Bean, onCellEdit method:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event)
     {  
            Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
            Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

            System.out.println(oldValue + " i druga: " + newValue + "    event: " + (String) event.getColumn().getHeaderText());

            if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue))
            {  
                System.out.println("rsedtcyfvubi" + oldValue + " i druga: " + newValue);
            }  
        }
```

Console info after update: *INFO: null i druga: null    event: Temat*

So: var event is not null but oldValue and newValue is null and I dont know why! Please help!
Btw, I have PF 4.0, Eclipse Kepler and GlassFish 4.0. And I've had enough of this...

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem and I was because my my DataTable.value was binded to a function like ManagedBean.getList(), instead of been binded to a field of the ManagedBean.

When I changed DataTable.value to bind to  a field of the ManagedBean it worked.

Comment: If you want more details, please copy the implementation of obslugaUzytkownikow.listaZadan()...